# mostrar datos de un selectbox en sql server

Tags: php, sql

Como dice mi pregunta, necesito saber como mostrar datos al seleccionar una opcion de un selectbox.

Mi codigo es el siguiente y uso SQL SERVER (vale la pena decirlo, ya que la mayoria de tutoriales son para mysql)

```
<?php
define('DB_SERVER','x.x.x.x');
define('DB_NAME','mydb');
define('DB_USER','sa');
define('DB_PASS','');

$conectar = mssql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
$conn = mssql_select_db(DB_NAME);


if( !$conn ) {
    echo "No se puede conectar a la Base de Datos.<br />";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$query = 'SELECT EntregaRendirCodigo FROM EntregasRendir';

$result = mssql_query($query);
if (!$result) 
{
    $message = 'ERROR: ' . mssql_get_last_message();
    return $message;
}
else
{
    $i = 0;
    echo '<html><body><select name="listbox" size="20">';
    while ($i < mssql_num_fields($result))
    {
        $meta = mssql_fetch_field($result, $i);
        echo '<td>' . $meta->EntregaRendirCodigo . '</td>';
        $i = $i + 1;
    }
    echo '</tr>';

    while ( ($row = mssql_fetch_row($result))) 
    {
        $count = count($row);
        $y = 0;
        echo '<tr>';
        while ($y < $count)
        {
            $c_row = current($row);
            echo '<option>' . $c_row . '</option>';
            next($row);
            $y = $y + 1;
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    mssql_free_result($result);

    echo '</select></body></html>';
}
?>
```

Soy nuevo en esto, y si pudieran brindarme algun tutorial, seria de gran ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si eres nuevo no te compliques mucho las cosas. Recurre a algo simple y a medida que vayas avanzando, ve modificando y actualizando el código.

```
Tabla articulos
id          nombre
------------------------
1           Soldador de Estaño
2           PC
3           Teclado

<?php
try {
   $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pruebas', 'root', '');
   $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
   catch(PDOException $e){
      echo "ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();
}

if(isset($_POST['estado'])){
$estado = $_POST['estado'];
echo 'Usted eligio: '. $estado.'<br><br>';
}
?>
<form action="select.php" method="post">
<select name="estado">
<option value="">Articulos</option>
<?php
$sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM articulos");
while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {
?>
<option value="<?=$row['nombre'];?>"><?=$row['nombre'];?></option>

<?php
}
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Consulta">
</form>
```

como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero haberte ayudado

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero no era lo que estaba buscando, Yo puedo mostrar la lista de la base de datos, pero mi problema es que cuando seleccione el item, este muestre datos que contiene dentro de el.
Me dejo entender ?

Comment: Disculpa, ya lo modifico

Comment: Listo, ya esta modificado. Ahora podrás ver lo que selecciones!